# Opposite of MySQL Insert command

Tags: php, html, mysql

What is the opposite of the MySQL `INSERT` Command?

I want to know how to delete users from a table without admin. I Googled everywhere but couldn't find it at all.

Here is my PHP file:

```
<?php
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$passcheck = $_POST["passcheck"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
if ( $username && $password && $passcheck && $email ) {
} else
    echo "Please enter all fields";
?>
...
<form action="register.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username"><br>
    <input type="password" name="password"><br>
    <input type="password" name="passcheck"><br>
    <input type="text" name="email"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
<?php
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$passcheck = $_POST["passcheck"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
if ( $username && $password && $passcheck && $email ) {
    $connect = mysql_connect( "localhost", "root", "root" ) or die("Couldn't connect!");
    mysql_select_db("login") or die("Couldn't find database!");
    $query = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'" );
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows( $query );
        if ( $numrows != 0 ) {
        echo "Username taken";
    } else
        if ( $password == $passcheck ) {
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email)
                VALUES ('$username','$password','$email')");
        } else
            echo "Passwords don't match";
} else
    echo "Please enter all fields";
?>
```

Comment: `DELETE FROM some_table WHERE some_column = some_value`

Comment: What on earth were you googling? "mysql delete" is filled with exactly what you need. Since you're clearly new to this, you should use PDO or mysqli to interact with databases. mysql_ is deprecated

Comment: Yes, @KaiQing is 100% correct. Your code is completely open to being hacked with a SQL Injection. In effect, your database will be pwned (and the data subsequently erased/corrupted) the moment anyone with a modicum of skill (or the name [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)) discovers your site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MySQL Delete statement is:

DELETE FROM table_name WHERE some_column = some_value;

Take a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_delete.asp

Answer (score 1):

DELETE  FROM some_table WHERE some_value=X;